# is_const<const int&>::value is false -- why?

Tags: c++, c++11

Why does this static assertion fire?

```
static_assert(std::is_const<const int&>::value, "Pain");
```

Would be awesome to get both a syntactic (why the implementation would do this) and a semantic reasoning (why they would have designed this type trait's interface to do this).

I am aware it is possible to throw in a `std::remove_reference` call to get the expected outcome, but I'm not sure why that's necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`const int&` is a reference to `const int`. So the reference itself isn't `const`.

It's slightly confusing, so I'm going to present an analogy with `const int*`. It's the pointer to `const int`. But you can modify it

```
const int a = 5, b = 7;
const int* ptr = &a;
ptr = &b; // pointer is modified
```

so the pointer isn't `const`. (the const pointer would be `int* const` instead)

Comment: However a reference cannot be modified (making it referencing something else) at all, so, more or less, every reference is actually `const`.

Comment: A reference is cannot be rebound so it is _effectively_ `const` but that is not the same as being semantically `const`.

Comment: Agreed. To remember, you can informally say "a const reference is not a reference that is const". You need to read "const reference" as not a "const" "reference", but a term that means something different altogether than the combination of both words.